# Ruby On Rails ActiveRecord select stuff with WHERE condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I have `Post` and `User` entities in my application.

They have `belongs_to` and `has_many` relationships accordingly. I use `gem devise` as user authorization/authentication system.

This piece of code selects all posts if `Post` has `user_id` and it's the same as `current_user.id`, and assigns it to the instance variable:

```
@post = Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

Question is:

**How could I select latest post created by user (I think I'd use `.last` method to achieve that)**

But the problem is that I don't know how to use `.where` and `.last` in one query inside of my instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ActiveRecord [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) method returns a ActiveRecord Relation Object. This means can just chain other AR methods onto it. There are several ways you can do this.

```
@post = Post.where(user: current_user)
```

Notice that you can pass `where` the object without specifying the id. For example, `where(user: current_user)` as opposed to `where(user_id: current_user.id)`. AR figures out what you are trying to do.

You can also go through the user.

```
@post = current_user.posts.last
```

But beware that [`last`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last) may not necessarily do what you want. It uses the object `id` by default. This means posts updated more recently may not take precedence. If you use soft deletes this could also be an issue. You might want to explicitly add the `created_at` or `updated_at` to the condition.

```
@post = current_user.posts.order(created_at: :desc).last
```

You might want to wrap this in a scope.

```
class Post
  scope :most_recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc).last }
end
@post = current_user.posts.most_recent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order the post created by the user in order of ascending or descending, to get the latest post by the user, you can order by descending.

In your post model can define a scope as recent

```
scope :recent,  -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

@post = current_user.posts.recent.first
```

Answer (score -2):

I have resolved my issue.

This worked for me like a charm:

```
@post = Post.joins(:user).where(posts: { user_id: current_user.id }).last
```

Comment: That's not a good way to go about this. You are doing an unecessary join.

Comment: Yes, will do refactoring after a few moments. Thanks for your answer!